# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier jquery ajax y laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax

estoy tratando de filtrar un datatable mediante un select y un boton, pero por consola veo que se me esta dando el error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (no me muestra especificamente linea ni nada).

El select lo cargo con datos que envio desde el controlador a la vista, y en el controlador tengo la funcion para mostrar los datos que necesito filtrar.

Para el select y el boton tengo este codigo:

```
 <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <select name="bodega_id" id="bodega_id" class="form-control col-lg-4">
                            <option value="" selected disabled>--Seleccione Bodega a Consultar--</option>
                            @foreach ($bodegas as $bodega)
                                <option value="{{ $bodega->id}}"> {{ $bodega->nombre_bodega}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        <button type="button" name="filtrar" id="filtrar" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Mostrar Inventario</button>
                    </div>
```

En el controlador tengo esta funcion:

```
public function inventarioPorBodega(Request $request){

        $bodegas  = Bodega::select('id','nombre_bodega')->get();

        if(request()->ajax()){
            if(!empty($request->bodega_id)){

                $data = DB::table('det_ingreso_materials as d')
                ->join('ingreso_materials as i', 'i.id', 'd.ingreso_material_id')
                ->join('materials as m', 'd.material_id','m.id')
                ->join('bodegas as b', 'd.bodega_id', 'b.id')
                ->join('servicios as s', 'i.servicio_id','s.id')
                ->join('clasificadors as c', 'm.clasificador_id','c.id')
              ->select('d.id', 'd.cantidad',
                'm.nombre_producto','m.sku','m.catalogo_telmex','m.unidad_medida','m.seriado',
                'b.nombre_bodega','b.tipo_bodega',
                's.servicio','c.clasificador') 
                ->where('b.id', $request->bodega_id)
                ->get();
            }
            return datatables()->of($data)->make(true);
        }
       return view('bodega.logistica.inventario.index',compact('bodegas'));
```

y en la vista tengo la tabla:

```
<table class="table table-head-fixed text-nowrap" id="inventario">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>tipo_bodega</th>
                    <th>material</th>
                    <th>unidad_medida</th>
                    <th>clasificador</th>
                    <th>servicio</th>
                    <th>sku</th>
                    <th>catalago_telmex</th>
                    <th>cantidad</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
              </table>
```

y el jquery/ajax:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    fill_datatable();

    function fill_datatable()
    {
        var dataTable = $('#inventario').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,

            ajax:{
                url:"{{ route('inventario.bodegas') }}",
                data:{ bodega_id:bodega_id},

            },
            columns:[
                    { data:'d.id', name:'id'},
                  { data:'tipo_bodega', name:'tipo_bodega'},
                    { data:'nombre_producto', name:'nombre_producto'},
                    { data:'unidad_medida', name:'unidad_medida'},
                    { data:'clasificador', name:'clasificador'},
                    { data:'servicio', name:'servicio'},
                    { data:'sku', name:'sku'},
                    { data:'catalogo_telmex', name:'catalogo_telmex'},
                    { data:'cantidad' name:'cantidad'},
            ],

        });
    }



        $('#filtrar').click(function(){
            var bodega_id = $('#bodega_id').val();
            if (bodega_id != '') {
                $('#inventario').DataTable().destroy();
                fill_datatable(bodega_id);
            }else{
                alert('Seleccione Bodega a Mostrar');
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

He estado leyendo y al parecer es por la forma de llamar al dato(data:cantidad, name:cantidad) pero probando con otras tablas da el mismo error.

Saludos a todos

Comment: tenes un cierre de comentario `*/` sin apertura despues de `{ data:'catalogo_telmex', name:'catalogo_telmex'},` y te falta una `,` en la linea de abajo de esa. Acá `{ data:'cantidad' name:'cantidad'}` cuando lo escribiste en el post lo escribiste bien pero en el código lo tenes mal.

Comment: Cambie el codigo del script, pero ahora me da este error:  jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation